# How to split a column of dictionary type into two different pandas column of different type?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe with 2 columns (plus index) like this, it has around 14,000 lines.

```
Employee                           | RecordID
{'Id': 185, 'Title': 'Full Name'}  |    9
```

I'd like to split the columns like this:

```
Id   |    Title      | RecordID
185  |  'Full Name'  |    9
```

I tried to use this solution:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_df["Employee"].values.tolist(), index=data_df.index) <- error
data_df = pd.concat([data_df, df2], axis = 1).drop(column, axis = 1)
```

but it gives this error on the `df2` line

```
 *** AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

I have 2 theories: one that it's because i have different column types in the employee dictionary, and two: there are 3 records that have an empty employee id, like this:

```
Employee                           | RecordID
nan                                |    7051
```

I need to keep those 3 records without an employee record and show their `record Id`, and in the final `data_df` show empty columns for employee id and employee name.

So in summary:

INPUT

```
Employee                           | RecordID
{'Id': 185, 'Title': 'Full Name'}  |    9
nan                                |    7051
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
Id   |    Title      | RecordID
185  |  'Full Name'  |    9
nan  |  nan          |    7051
```

I made it work using `data_df["Employee"].apply(pd.Series)` but it's painfully slow.

Is there a way *not* using `pd.series` to split a column of dictionaries where such dictionary has different column types and nan values to separate columns into the parent pandas dataframe?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
data_df1= data_df.dropna()

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data_df1["Employee"].values.tolist(), index= data_df1.index)

data_df=data_df.join(df2,how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! ah I see, create the dataframe, filter out nulls, convert the column to dataframe, then left join.  I didn't realize one can do that with dataframes.  I'll verify tomorrow and, if everything goes ok, mark this as an answer.

Comment: After your answer i looked up docs on `dropna`, would you recommend using it only on the first column? `df.dropna(subset = ['Employee'])`

Comment: @JoseR it is better only do the first columns